# onItemClick of listview and a loop inside case

Tags: java, android, listview, colors, crash

my purpose is to make the item selected (from the listview) become highlighted.
And it works perfectly using the code below:

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int post,
                    long arg3) {

                int itemPosition = post;
                String itemValue = (String) lst_peers
                        .getItemAtPosition(itemPosition);
                sendMessage(itemValue + " has been selected!");

                obOpponent = new Opponent(peerListID.get(itemPosition),
                        itemValue);

                // turning off the discovery process if any
                discTime = 0;

                // set the item highlighted
                lst_peers.setItemChecked(itemPosition, true);
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

            }
```

but, my question is 
how to make the item back to normal state color (unhighlighted),
once the user click another item?

i tried to put loop inside the onItemClick method, but the android crashed!

Comment: Better to used `Selector` and set to your `ListItem` as Background ...

Comment: If you're using a custom adapter, you should do this inside the getView() method of the adapter.

Comment: what, when did the getView() is executed anyway? @ShivamVerma

Comment: @gumuruh Whenever you set adapter and whenever you call `notifydataSetChanged()`, `getView()` is called for each of the position of your element. Note : It's not guaranteed that how many times `getView()` will be called for the same position.

Comment: how about the setOnItemClickListener() is that method also calling notifydataSetChanged() or getView() ? @AndroidWarrior..

Comment: @gumuruh No `setOnItemClickListener()` doesn't call `notifyDataSetChanged()` but yes while clicking any item if your listView gets scrolled it'll call `getView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer 1 - the fastest:

Try a little trick:

Define a global View variable `View TempView` and use it to store your `View arg1` for later (next click) change it to the original background:

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int post,
                long arg3) {

            int itemPosition = post;
            String itemValue = (String) lst_peers
                    .getItemAtPosition(itemPosition);
            sendMessage(itemValue + " has been selected!");

            obOpponent = new Opponent(peerListID.get(itemPosition),
                    itemValue);

            // turning off the discovery process if any
            discTime = 0;

            // set the item highlighted
            lst_peers.setItemChecked(itemPosition, true);
            if (!(tempView == null)) {
                    tempView.setBackgroundColor(YOUR_ORIGINAL_BACKGROUND);
                }
                tempView = arg1;
                tempView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            

        }
```

anytime you click, change to the color to yellow, and the previously clicked go back to original color you want.

## Answer 2 - the better one - selector

in your xml, add to your listview `android:listSelector="@drawable/yourselector" >`
which is a xml file where you implement your click events inside listview, like sample below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_enabled="true"> 
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
       <gradient
          android:startColor="#6018d7e5"
          android:centerColor="#6016cedb"
          android:endColor="#6009adb9"
          android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <!-- (...)
   </item>
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false">
      <!-- (...)
   </item>
    
 </selector>
```

Comment: great to know your solutions @PedroHawk.... Perhaps you could help me also in some other topic? Here: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/247000/wifi-communication-between-two-device-without-intermediary-device or maybe here : https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/249758/proximity-sdk-alternatives-for-android